# Database with time in fullcalendar Not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fullcalendar

We are saved `FromTime` and `ToTime` value from database below attached image:
[image]

```
var events = [];
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/Booking/GetEvents",
        success: function (data) {
            $.each(data, function (i, v) {
                events.push({
                    title: v.EventName,
                    description: v.Description,
                    start: moment(v.BookedFromDate).moment(v.FromTime),
                    end: v.BookedToDate != null ? moment(v.BookedToDate) : null,
                    name: v.ParticipantName,
                    className: 'event-red'
                });
            })

            GenerateCalender(events);
        },
        error: function (error) {
            alert('failed');
        }
    })
```

In this Code i need to get FromTime Value but in my code not working..

```
start: moment(v.BookedFromDate).moment(v.FromTime),
```

I need to display date and time

Comment: It is not a good idea to reveal your db tables or db server snapshot

Comment: okay any idea how To get time value @GeorgeBailey

Comment: can you show how your `data` looks like ? use `console.log` to log its value

Comment: If i using `start: '2016-01-16T16:00:00',` like this code working but i need to get database time

Comment: have you tried to use moment js? https://momentjs.com/

Comment: okay sir @Yahel...

Comment: One moment object would make more sense to parse the whole string... e.g. `start: moment(v.BookedFromDate + " " + v.FromTime);` You might have to supply a custom time format to momentJS so that it understands your AM/PM strings. See http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/ . Better still - don't store dates and times as strings in your database!! the `datetime` datatype exists for several very good reasons.